# How do I link to the same page on a different domain?

Tags: html, wildcard

I'm working on a localization project and until we get translations working on site abc.com, we created site def.com as a mirror for a foreign language.

We are putting a language selector on abc.com with a static link to def.com, but I want the user to be taken to the same page in the site hierarchy, *not the homepage* when they click. The site structures have been mirrored exactly, so we are not concerned about 404's.

To be clear, I need a way of doing this on a link click, we do not want to redirect using .htaccess or other server-side methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you could do is add a click event in Javascript, get the current URL, and modify the string to be the appropriate domain.

```
//get the URL in JS
var urlStr = window.location.href;

//where abc and def are your languages.
//Note you'll switch the order for the other site (You can also just do a simple check)
var newUrlStr = str.replace("abc", "def");

//redirect to new url
window.location = newUrlStr;
```

It's not what I would call pretty, but it would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Window.location.pathname will give you the page you are on, not including the domain.
Something like this should work:

```
document.getElementById("idOfMyLink").click(function(){
 window.location.href = "def.com" + window.location.pathname;
});
```

If you want to also include query strings(?query=value) or hashes (#anchor), you can use this:

```
document.getElementById("idOfMyLink").click(function(){
 window.location.href = "def.com" + window.location.pathname  + "?" + window.location.search + "#" window.location.hash;
});
```